# Cannot find code css/html in file structure

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of an issue.

I have this line of code..

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

..that I cannot find anywhere in the website, both CSS and HTML files.
Where this possibly come from? I've checked the index.php file, the header.

It's viewable in the first page of the website. I looked in the source, it's there. But I cannot find the line of code in the files of the websites.

Care to help?

EDIT: It seems Chrome (as a browser) adds this line to the index.php. Weird!

Comment: Maybe a javascript function adds it somewhere. ANyway we can't do much here, you're the only one that can search through all the source files

Comment: Maybe some of your brwser plugin

Comment: The code seems to load CSS from a HTML structure, but when looking for it in the .php files of the WP, there is no line like this.

Comment: understand your source code ....

Comment: Since the code is inside <style> it must be in the index.php

Comment: M1K1O, I've checked the website in another browser and it's fine. It seems Chrome adds this line in the website and moves the website down completely with 32px. Well, is there a solution for this? Anyway, thanks for replies everybody!

Comment: If you use certain free hosting services, sometimes they'll add certain elements into your pages, perhaps this is something you might want to inquire about.

Comment: @AndrewB, thank you but the website it's not hosted on a free hosting website.

Comment: which framework are you using????

Comment: It's a WordPress website with a custom theme. This line appears in the index.php (while I look at the source), but when I go to templates, the line isn't there - and the template has less info in comparation to the source I viewed.

Comment: It might just be a javascript function, but when viewed in another browsers there is no CSS like the line I posted. There is no `html { margin-top: 32px !important; }`. I think it's from Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

superblana,

These lines must somewhere in your templates files or in your index.php .
If you say it's in your source code, make sure you're looking to the source code send by the server (with Ctrl+U for example) and not the DOM gerenerated by the browser.

So I think it must be in your index.php or somewhere in you're templates. Check in you're PHP, maybe it's included or generated by a function or something.

Comment: thanks for replying. Well, the first page of the website is very different from the template's index.php. Less information in the template, rather than the information there is in the SOURCE VIEW of the actual index.php. I'll look into the templates carefully. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe your theme is using home.php instead of index.php as the homepage template.